# Prove that a recurrent class is also an absorbing class

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I believe this statement to be true since the definition of recurrence means that in the long run, there will be infinitely many revisits to this class. I am thinking that I should show $P_{AA} = 1$, where $P$ is the probability transition matrix and $A$ is the said class.

I am trying to use this theorem $P_{AA}^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n f_{AA}^{(k)}P_{AA}^{(n-k)}$, where the $(n)$ represents the $n$th step, to prove absorbance so I can use that fact that $f_{AA} = 1$ since $A$ is a recurrent class.

Am I on the right track? If not, how should I go about proving it because I am kind of stuck on moving forward from the equation.

Comment: What is $P_{AA}$ when $A$ is class of states?

Comment: It would be $P(X_{n+1} = A | X_{n} = A)$?

Comment: Is $A$ a single state or a class of states. $X_n=A$ does not make sense if $A$ is a class of states.

Comment: It would be a class of states. I am not sure why it would not make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

The key points that you need are

1. The probability of moving from one class to a different class and subsequently returning to the first class is $0$.
2. If you have positive probability of leaving a class directly from one of its states, you have positive probability of eventually leaving the class from any of its states.

Both of these facts follow from the definition of communicating classes.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure how do I use that fact that it is recurrent?

Comment: @keith It's easier to go the other way - prove that if it's not absorbing then it's not recurrent.

Comment: I think I know how to approach it now, thanks so much! @Especially Lime